# Arguement Validation in sequence

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have arguments passed by user like below-

```
FILE_DIR=${1}

RETENTION_DAYS=${2}

FILE_NAME_PREFIX=${3}

For Validation I use-

if [ $# -ne 3  ]
then
        fn_usage
fi
```

But I don't know what to do if user gives RETENTION_DAYS as 3rd argument or if user gives FILE_NAME_PREFIX as 1st argument.
Can anybody help?

Comment: Better use `getopts`

Comment: What could be alternate option? Could you write a code for that?

Comment: No, search, there's tons of examples around

Comment: The way you code above let us understand that your command uses positional parameters: FILE_DIR is always the first argument, RETENTION_DAYS always the second and FILE_NAME_PREFIX the third. The last phrase of your question makes no sense to us. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @user8367639 : Garbage in, garbage out. You could parse the arguments and conclude that a non-numeric argument can't be the retention days, but since the file name prefix can be a number too, you would have to load the famous mind-reading module to find out what the user wants.

Comment: `getopts` doesn't really help that much. Now instead of `script somedir 20 foo`, you have to write `script --dir somedir --numdays 20 --prefix foo`, which is way more verbose, implies that some or all of the values are optional, and *still* doesn't prevent `script --dir 20 --numdays foo --prefix somedir`. At some point, the contract of "caller documents the interface, and the callee respects it" has to be honored.

Comment: As @PierreFrançois said, I need FILE_DIR is always the first argument, RETENTION_DAYS always the second and FILE_NAME_PREFIX the third. I do not want the user to give FILE_NAME_PREFIX as 1st argument instead of FILE_DIR

Comment: No worries issue has been resolved, created a usage function that tells the user how to pass arguments and as I validate those three arguments, I have added the usage function. Thanks all!!